# MASM Frame not in module the current stack frame was not found in a loaded module

Tags: assembly, winapi, x86-64, calling-convention, masm64

I'm currently learning MASM x64 and using Visual Studio 2022. To facilitate my learning process, I've attempted to create a simple `WriteLine` procedure that I can call from the main function to write a new line. (It might be worth mentioning that `WriteLine` and `main` are in different files.)

However, when `WriteLine` attempts to return, I encounter the following error:

```
"0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x0000000000000000."
```

Additionally, a new window pops up displaying the following message:

```
"Frame not in module - The current stack frame was not found in a loaded module. Source cannot be shown for this location."
```

Here is the `WriteLine` code:

```
extern GetStdHandle: proc
extern WriteFile: proc

.data

newLine db 13,10
written dq ?

.code

    WriteLine PROC

    mov rcx, -11
    call    GetStdHandle    
    mov rcx, rax           
    mov rdx, offset newLine  
    mov r8, 2            
    mov r9, written        
    call    WriteFile      

    ret 
    
    WriteLine ENDP
    END
```

And here is some sample code from `main`:

```
extern GetStdHandle: proc
extern WriteFile: proc
extern WriteLine: proc

.data
...
.code

main PROC

    ...
    call WriteLine
    ...

    ret

    main ENDP
    END
```

I've tried cleaning the solution and thought making `WriteLine` and/or `main` public would help, but it hasn't worked.

Comment: You aren't following the x64 calling conventions at all.  64-bit code is very different from 32-bit code.  You have to allocate space on the stack for the arguments plus a "spill" area, EVEN IF all of the arguments are passed in registers.  You need to read this:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=msvc-170

Comment: It's not a linking error, it's just that your debugger doesn't know where to look for source code after returning to RIP=0 (which happened because your return address was in the shadow space owned by the functions you called.)